# Derived exception does not inherit constructors

Tags: c++, oop, exception, inheritance, constructor

I have a problem with the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class MyException : public std::logic_error {
};

void myFunction1() throw (MyException) {
    throw MyException("fatal error");
};

void myFunction2() throw (std::logic_error) {
    throw std::logic_error("fatal error");
};

int main() {
    try {
        myFunction1();
        //myFunction2();
    }catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Error.\n"
            << "Type: " << typeid(e).name() << "\n"
            << "Message: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`throw MyException("fatal error");` line does not work. Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 says this:

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const char [12]' to 'MyException'
```

MinGW's reaction was very similar.

It means, that the constructor `std::logic_error(const string &what)` was not *copied* from the parent class into the child. Why?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inheriting constructors is a C++11 feature which is not available in C++03 (which you seem to be using, as I can tell from the dynamic exception specifications).

However, even in C++11 you would need a `using` declaration to inherit a base class's constructor:

```
class MyException : public std::logic_error {
public:
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};
```

In this case, you just have to write explicitly a constructor that takes an `std::string` or a `const char*` and forwards it to the base class's constructor:

```
class MyException : public std::logic_error {
public:
    MyException(std::string const& msg) : std::logic_error(msg) { }
};
```

Comment: I use C++11 in another project, where I met this problem for a first time. How can I do that `using` part?
Anyway, your solution works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @ArturIwan: Sorry for the late answer, had to leave for a while. I updated the answer to show the syntax. However, I think VC11 does not support inheriting constructors.

Comment: I have test your "using" solution and as you said, Visual Studio does not support it yet.

Comment: @ArturIwan: Yes, sadly VC11 is far from being fully C++11 compliant.

Comment: I find it amazing how quick we run into sheisse when using c++11, even 4 years later. VC12 also does not support inheriting constructors. only the CTP does. c.f.: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx . fortunately for us VC14 (yes they skipped 13) is to be out in 2 weeks or something.